# SVN how to remove local copy only?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

Here is the scenario ... I am also using tortoise SVN ...

I can create a new folder and do a checkout with the "only this item" option ... this will checkout just the top level folder, I can then go into the repo browser and select any subfolder i want to "update to revision" (in the repo browser right click, select update to revision) ... this will bring down only that subfolder ...

**Is there a way to remove the folder without removing it from the repository?**

If not, my other option is to simply checkout the subprojects individually (this might be the best solution), lets see if anyone has an answer to the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking out the subdirectories (which can be treated as repositories in their own right) individually, as you suggested is the cleanest way to do this.  That's pretty common with folks who I've seen have SVN repositories that look like this from the root

```
/
  /proj1
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
  /proj2
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
```

Comment: A problem with this approach (at least in my case) is that a sparse checkout will not include the external folders. What if (and that's my case) I would like to remove a folder from the local working copy while at the same time keeping the external folders?

Answer (score 12):

I'm a bit late to the game but I've just had the same question and not found a satisfactory answer.

The answer I came up with was to do a full checkout then

1. update to revision...
2. update depth -> choose items...
3. untick any items you don't want.

ticking make depth sticky then retains this depth over future updates.

Answer (score 6):

To remove a previously checked out folder from your local repo, without it being marked as deleted, use this command:

```
svn update <yourfolder> --set-depth=exclude
```

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the folder from your local working directory it won't affect the version in the repository. Only when you do a 'svn delete' and commit the changes will it actually delete the directory from the repository.

Comment: It only effects his working copy, but this also means that `svn stat` is going to show a "!" status for those missing files/directories and Windows Explorer/Tortoise will show a "!" in the parent directory and greyed out versions of those missing directories/files (iirc, I haven't used Tortoise in a long time).  Further, everytime he `svn up`'s in the parent directory or above, he's going to get those files back.  Not a huge problem, but annoying, nonetheless.