# How to manage svn Subversion (svn) large tags local folder?

Tags: wordpress, svn

I am WordPress plugin developer and over the years my tags folder on my local machine has filled up with all the major/minor releases, now close to 500 Mb.  I use `svn` only for pushing plugin releases to the WordPress repo.  I use GitHub for development.  So I don't need all the branches created under the `tags` folder which have been piling up.

Is there a way to remove the local tags versions and still commit/push releases into the tags folder on the svn repo?

I tried looking at the documentation on this but could not find any leads.
I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58735908/3596672), but it does not give much details:

```
svn update <yourfolder> --set-depth=exclude
```

the `set-depth=exclude` ([command doc](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.set_depth)) apparently allows the configuration of [sparse directories](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) which only do a shallow sync with the repo.

Can this be used on the `tags` folder in order to disconnect the link to the repo and still push updates with `svn copy trunk tags/...` ?

Can anyone shed some light on this ?